# Review Actions - Reviewing multiple items

Tags: google-schemas

I am playing around with the review actions, more specifically with the movie review example. Suppose that you want to review different characteristics of the movie, like sound, special fx, etc. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the `ReviewAction` can only be used with quick single-rating reviews. The user experience for more complex reviews inside a small dropdown in Gmail will be poor, so those should be handled on a dedicated site.